# I need my bibliography style for the journal "International Interactions"

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I am trying to conform to the bibliography style guide for the journal [International Interactions](https://www.isanet.org/Publications/II). I can't find a standard bibliography style that fits their criteria. It's similar to APA (e.g., year in parentheses after the author block), but they want no comma after the journal name, they want the first names spelled out, and they want a dot ("period") at the end of the author block (and immediately before the year).

I've tried setting the bibliography style as `apalike`, `newapa`, and maybe 50 others, but none seem to both make the first names spelled out and remove the comma after the journal name. I found one (forgot which) that did those things but then made the journal number bold. The style that seems closest to what they want is `apalike`, but it has the comma after journal name and shortens the author first names in the bibliography to initials.

I'm hoping there's an easy solution. I'm using TeXworks on a Mac, and `natbib`, my sources are in BidDesk.

Thanks!

Here's a MWEB:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib} 
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@article{graham2005economic,
  title={The economic implications of corporate financial reporting},
  author={Graham, John R and Harvey, Campbell R and Rajgopal, Shiva},
  journal={Journal of Accounting and Economics},
  volume={40},
  number={1},
  pages={3--73},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Let's cite \cite{graham2005economic}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname} 

\end{document}
```

My in-text citation call-outs are fine. My book entries seem fine, except the first name should be spelled out. The articles need first name spelled out, no punctuation after the journal title, and a period after the author block.

Here is how they want books:

> Anderson, Benedict. (1983) *Imagined Communities*. Revised edition. London: Verso.

Here is how they want articles:

> Anderson, Benedict. (1983) The New World Disorder. *New Left Review* 193(6):3–13.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide code for a minimal document demonstrating the issue i.e. an MWEB (Minimal Working Example with Bibliography). I've removed the `texworks` tag as your editor and platform are irrelevant. I've added `bibtex` since you are presumably using that, given the `natbib`. Please state whether you are required to use `natbib` and BibTeX or whether Biblatex/Biber is an option.

Comment: 'Similar to APA' sounds like the game of a thousand tweaks, asked for one-by-one (which is fine if you're willing to ask the questions one-by-one). You might you can speed the process along by providing a description of the actual style, however. (In addition to the MWE+B already requested.)

Comment: Your description of the required formatting elements is highly incomplete. How should entries *not* of type `@article` be formatted? Your write-up is also (probably unintentionally!) misleading: For instance, the `apacite` bibliography style inserts a comma, not a period, after the name of the journal. You should provide a link to the webpage that lists the formatting requirements exhaustively.

Comment: @jon  Thanks for the quick responses. This is my first time asking a question here so I appreciate the help.

Comment: @cfr - thanks for the help - I added a MWEB to the question above. Yes, bibtex and natbib. I'm not required to use natbib; Biblatex/Biber should be fine.

Comment: @jon - Thanks for the help. I edited my initial question to show how the journal wants articles and books. \bibliographystyle{apalike} gets things almost right, I just need the first names to not be made into initials, and there should be no comma after the journal title. Thanks!

Comment: @Mico - Thanks for the help. You're right, it's a comma I'm trying to remove. I included in my initial questions the book format they want.

Comment: In cases such as yours, i.e., when making just one or two tweaks to an existing bibliography style won't work, the recommendation is almost invariably to run the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib) package, to create a bespoke bibliography style file that incorporates all of your formatting requirements. Type `latex makebst` at a command prompt and follow the instructions; you'll be asked a series of multiple-choice questions, and at the end of the process you'll have a custom bibliography style (bst) file.

Comment: @Mico Or to switch to Biblatex/Biber which is easier to customise by far.

Comment: I've perused the journal's formatting instructions, and I find them rather spotty and incomplete. For instance, no real mention is made of how entries with three or more authors should be formatted. Very discouraging, really. I think your best bet is to contact the journal's editorial staff to (a) raise these issues -- they may not even be aware of them! -- and (b) ask them if it's OK to go ahead and use a bibliography style such as `apalike`.

Comment: I've got biber running for a short document. If I do \usepackage[backend=biber,uniquename=false,style=authoryear,autocite=inline]{biblatex}, I need to put parentheses around the volume number.

Comment: @cfr I switched to biber but I'm having trouble finding easy documentation showing how to customize. If I do style=apa or style=authoryear, each of those gets me close but not quite there. With style=apa, I need to remove commas in in-line citations, remove the comma after journal name in bibliography, and spell out the author first names in the bibliography.

Comment: @Mico - I tried makebst. That almost worked! One thing I can't figure out - somehow there is no period after the author name in the bibliography. I couldn't figure out how to edit my custom bst file so I did the whole thing again, and I did it again - I guess they framed the question in a way I misunderstood. How can I edit the bst  to put periods in after author name in the bibliography?

Comment: @Mico - actually I have a period after the year (which is in parentheses) and I'm supposed to have the period before year (after the author). I figured out how to open the bst code in TexShop, but it's pretty hard to understand for a first-timer, I'm not sure where to make the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you proceed in two steps. First, create a new bst (bibliography style) file using the interactive `makebst` utility. (Open a command window and type `latex makebst` to get started.) Second, it will be necessary to make a minor edit, by hand, in the newly created bst file.

---

While answering the interactive, multiple-choice questions posed by `makebst`, choosing the default answer is correct in most instances. (That's why they're the defaults, right?) In same cases, though, you'll need to choose a non-default answer. The most important such cases are as follows:

[image]

```
...
```

[image]

```
...
```

[image]

```
...
```

[image]

```
...
```

[image]

```
...
```

[image]

```
...
```

[image]

```
...
```

---

Let's assume you've named the new file `ii-experimental.bst`. Open this file in a text editor -- the program you use to edit your tex files will do fine -- and locate the function `format.authors`. It should look like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names }
```

Change the code block to

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
    "." *
}
```

I.e., add a new line that contains `"." *`. As you can probably guess, this additional instruction serves to add a dot ("period", "full stop") immediately after the final name in the author block.

---

In your main tex file, be sure to change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` to `ii-experimental.bst` (or whatever you chose to name the file). Save the new bst file either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.

Last but not least, assuming you're using the `natbib` citation management package (with the option `longnamesfirst`), you should (a) use `\citep` exclusively to create citation call-outs, as all citation call-outs are supposed to be in "parenthetic" style, and (b) run the instruction

```
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
```

after loading `natbib`, to suppress the comma between the author(s)'s surname(s) and the year(s). Finally, perform a full recompile cycle -- latex, bibtex, and latex twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!